# How to identify, all elements in the html page have been rendered?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, settimeout

I would like to add a loading image to my page. I have added my loading image at the beginning of my body tag, and I have removed loading image at the end of HTML tag. Now I am able to identify, when, Js files are completely downloaded. But, how to make sure that all elements in the page have been completely rendered? Now, I am using `setTimeOut` function to add extra one second delay. Is there a way to identify, all elements in the HTML page have been rendered?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? Like jquery or angular?

Comment: No. I am not using any frameworks. @bukkehariprasad

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    //do everything here
  }
}
```

The readyState property is used to determine the state of the document. Refer MDN docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Comment: Thanks for your answer bukke. But still document.readyState fires before the rendering process. how to indentify if the rendering process has been complete.